# Bootstrap Carousel Customization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to front-end and I'm using bootstrap for it. I seem to have issues in customizing it . The issues that I'm facing is, the picture is not within the left & right controller. How do I customize the image and controller so it fits into one frame ?

p/s this is my first time with StackOverflow.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
    <div class = "col-xs-12" >

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 486px; height:324px" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <%= image_tag("chart_1st_img.png", :class =>"img-responsive", :alt => "Chart 1", :width => "486", :height => "324" )%>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <br>
            <br>
        <h3>Pie Charts</h3>
        <p> Beatiful designed data. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <%= image_tag("chart_2nd_img.png", :class =>"img-responsive", :alt => "Chart 2")%>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Customer Hapiness</h3>
        <p>Overall Report</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <%= image_tag("charts_3rd_img.png", :class =>"img-responsive", :alt => "Chart 3" )%>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3> Various Graphics </h3>
        <p> i dont know what to describe</p>
      </div>
    </div>

   
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"  data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kn7rxzun/) is my fiddle.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Now, why have you mentioned `ruby-on-rails` tag ? And please post a fiddle(jsfiddle.net) link so the SO users can help you more !

Answer (score 0):

Please remove width and or replace by 100%

Comment: It's still the same tho :/

Comment: It still looks like this . checkout at the link below http://s1068.photobucket.com/user/Purry_Wijendra/media/bootstrap_zpsydkhjg8c.jpeg.html

Comment: do you want image in full width?

Comment: Just want it to fit within the frame

Comment: you can check by remove width and height and add width:100% in class